# How to embed PDF viewer in DSPACE

Tags: pdf, dspace, pdf-viewer

How can I embed PDF viewer in my DSPACE instance. I have tried many solution but nothing works. There are many suggestion on DSPACE official site
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Document+Viewer+Integration
No soluton has a documnetation how to configure these viewer in dspace code.
I want a step wise soultion for embeding PDF Viewer. Please help me out of this problem. Thanks in advance.

I have researched through these site -
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Document+Viewer+Integration
http://peterpants.blogspot.com/2010/02/document-preview-in-dspace-using-google.html

Comment: Have you tried the instructions here? [Document Preview with Google Docs viewer](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Document+Preview+with+Google+Docs+viewer) Also, you did not state what version of DSpace you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which version and which UI of DSpace you are using. I will describe roughly what we did to embed PDF.js into DSpace 6.3 JSPUI. We released all necessary code changes on [github](https://github.com/the-library-code/pdf-preview/tree/dspace-6.3-addition), so please take a look over there for details.

DSpace uses maven overlays to separate local code changes from the officially released code. Therefore, I will use paths within these overlays in the following description. If files that we changed do not exists within your local code repository, you have to copy them from there original location within `[dspace-source]/dspace-jspui/src/main`. It should also work if you do the code changes directly there, but I would consider that bad practice.

We added [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and all files it needs to `dspace/modules/jspui/src/main/webapp/static/pdfjs`. We then changed `dspace/modules/jspui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/webui/jsptag/ItemTag.java`. This class builds the item view. While I wish there would be a better separation of concerns, some HTML code is generated by this class, including the section of the item view that list all bitstreams. For every file that is listed, we check if its mime type is set to `application/pdf` and add a "preview" button for those files. The preview button links to the html site that renders the pdf viewer and loads the targeted file. We also added an attribute "download" to the default "Open/View" button, to ensure that it does not start another PDF viewer of the browser, but downloads the file. This is important to have one button called "preview" that opens the embeded PDF viewer and one button "download" that downloads the file to the user's computer. You can change the name of the button from "open/view" into "download" in the DSpace's message catalog. Last but not least we added JavaScript to `dspace/modules/jpsui/src/main/webapp/display-item.jsp`. The JavaScript suppress that the PDF viewer is loaded as a normal site, but loads it as an overlay over the item view, using JQuery UI. Then we wrote a small CSS file that helps us to position that overlay within the item view and referenced that file in `dspace/modules/jspui/src/main/webapp/layout/header-default.jsp`.

As mentioned above all these changes are published as open source under the DSpace Source Code BSD License on [github](https://github.com/the-library-code/pdf-preview/tree/dspace-6.3-addition).

Comment: Thank you very very much... solved my issue in dspace 6.3. Thanks once again......Just want to ask where to change in dspace 5.6....can i change the same in /dspace-jspui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/webui/jsptag/ItemTag.java and copy the pdfjs folder to  /dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp/static/

Comment: You can copy any file under dspace-jspui to dspace/modules/jspui and change it there. Besides that, you would have to back port our changes to the API of DSpace 5. It should not be much work, but you cannot expect the code to run without changes on DSpace 5. You can try to manually add the code we changed into DSpace 5 and see where you IDE or compiler complains about API calls it cannot resolve and then fix those. Besides that, please update to 5.10!

Comment: Yes some API call gives an error..reading errors carefully and sorting out now everything is working..thanks a lot.